# ¿Por qué no puedo agregar classList dentro de un for en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un listado de productos "estilo Amazon" y me funciona bien. El problema que a la hora de agregar una clase  `classList.add` dentro de un `for` me da error y no se imprime el listado de productos. Esta es la variable `var RibbonColor = document.querySelectorAll('#RibbonColor');` que no logro agregar dicha clase a `RibbonColor.classList.add("bg-success");` en la iteración.

**Error en consola:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Javascript:**

```
fetch('http://tiendavirtual.com:8080/api/productos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(datos => {
        mostrar(datos)
    });

function mostrar(datos) {
    ListadoProductos.innerHTML = '';

    for(let producto of datos["productos"]){

        var RibbonColor = document.querySelectorAll('#RibbonColor');
RibbonColor.classList.add("bg-success");

        ListadoProductos.innerHTML += `
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="">
                <div id="Ribbon" class="ribbon-wrapper">
                    <div id="RibbonColor" class="ribbon bg-success text-white">
                      ${ rRibbons }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://tiendavirtual.com:8080/img/productos/${departamento}/${ producto.Codigo }.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="">
                </a>     
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    <p class="card-title m-0">
                        <strong><a href="#">${ NombreProducto }</strong></a>
                    </p>
                    <hr class="bg-danger mt-0 mb-1">
                    <p class="card-text text-center text-muted  mb-0">${ producto.marca.Marca } <span class="badge badge-primary">Primary</span></p>     
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer p-1">
                    <p class="h3 text-center mb-0">$${ producto.PrecioV }</p>
                    <p class="text-center text-muted mb-0">Antes: <del>$${ producto.PrecioA }</del> / ${x }</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`; 
    }
}
```

Comment: [`querySelectorAll( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) devuelve **una lista**, no un elemento. **No puedes** obtener la `classList` de una lista.

Comment: mmm, y alguna solución o alternativa para agregar clases?

Comment: [¿`getElementById( )` ?](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Lo probe con `getElementById` y me da el mismo error..

Comment: Pues no existirá ningún elemento con el `id` por el que has preguntado.

Comment: pues si, se trata de una lista de productos en donde `<div id="RibbonColor" class="ribbon bg-success>` aparece varias veces con el mismo id por lo que supuse que `querySelectorAll( )` sería la mejor opción pero no me da los resultados esperados.`

Comment: Por favor, [edit] la pregunta adecuadamente para que represente el problema real; o elimínala ( y crea un pregunta nueva si lo estimas conveniente ).

Comment: Debes agregar el código `HTML` del elemento o elementos sobre los cuales estás realizando las operaciones.

Comment: si estas buscando por ID deberias usar: document.querySelector('#RibbonColor'); 
query selector all es para obtener un array de objetos que hagan match. Pero si buscas por ID debes tener un ID unico por cada elemento del dom.